# Maximum HttpUrlConnection Response

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpUrlConnection to get JSON strings from web, but the response is good for smaller strings but not for larger ones: [this](http://pastebin.com/NRU7nGXV/) is what I am seeing in my app, and [this](http://pastebin.com/WU2afcPd) is the data from server to a web page I did not include any HTML from server side.

Here is my code:

```
URL adr = new URL("http://placeform.tk/forapp.php");
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) adr.openConnection();
connection.connect();
int rcode = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.d("rcode",Integer.toString(rcode));
if (rcode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream inputStreamReader = connection.getInputStream();
    String c = connection.getHeaderField("content-length");
    Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(inputStreamReader);
    Log.d("contentsize", Integer.toString(connection.getContentLength()) + c);
    chars = new char[connection.getContentLength()];
    Log.d("contentsize", Integer.toString((int)connection.getContentLength()) + c);
    rd.read(chars);
    String output = new String(chars);
```

Comment: put the code where you parse the json

Comment: i have not done that part yet, but when  i checked the response of connection using log,,,this is what i found [read from logcat](http://pastebin.com/NRU7nGXV/) @UğurB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [this](http://aiyazparmar.blogspot.in/2016/02/call-web-service-andorid-wihout-using.html) link and add that class in your project and call webservice from that class. cause that class will build up your response string with use of string builder. have a look at that class. and comment if you have any problem.